# Parsing Single XML Node From Web Service Response

Tags: java, android, xml, web-services, parsing

I have seen a few questions in this general area, but cannot find anything specific to Java and pulling a single node value.

I have a Web Service that returns values formatted like so:

```
<string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">Hello</string>
```

In the Android application, I am trying to retrieve the 'Hello' part in the middle without the `XML` tags.

I have currently a method like so to do this:

```
public static String getParsedString(String xml)
{
    try
    {
        DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = documentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        InputSource input = new InputSource();
        StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(xml);
        input.setCharacterStream(stringReader);

        Document document = documentBuilder.parse(input);

        NodeList nodes = document.getElementsByTagName("string");
        return nodes.item(0).getNodeValue().toString();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}
```

However the node being parsed apparently contains no data, as when trying the `toString()` method, it throws the following error.

> java.lang.NullPointerException

I'm not sure I need to account for the `xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"` in the document parser, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: First try for the xml root element and then look for particular element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the line

```
return nodes.item(0).getNodeValue().toString();
```

to

```
return nodes.item(0).getTextContent();
```